# Recursive insert function for Node with 4 pointers returns null

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list

I am building essentially a linked lists that can travel in 4 different directions. The vital concepts are as follows:

- `Node` is a class in this scenario, with four `Node` pointers as class members.
- `Data` and `Coordinates` are also classes. `Data` is simply data that the node will contain.
- `raw_coordinates` are the coordinates that the new node should have.
- `Position` is the coordinates of the current node.
- `moveNorth`, `moveSouth`, `moveEast`, and `moveWest` return a new coordinate that reflect a change in position. For example, the position node might have coordinates (0,0). `moveNorth` takes the position and returns (0,1).

Lastly I would like to state that I am not concerned with the child node not point to the parent node. (i.e not interested if the node, node->north, has a valid node->south that returns to the previous node).

The issue is that my function returns `null`. Here is my code:

```
Node* Map::insertNode(Node *node, Data raw_data, Coordinates raw_coordinates, Coordinates position)
{
    if (node == NULL)
    {
        if (compare_coordinates(raw_coordinates, position))
        {
            return (newNode(raw_data, raw_coordinates));
        }
        else
        {
            return node;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (insertNode(node->north,raw_data, raw_coordinates, moveNorth(position)) != NULL)
        {
            node->north = insertNode(node->north, raw_data, raw_coordinates, moveNorth(position));
        }
        else if (insertNode(node->south,raw_data, raw_coordinates, moveSouth(position)) != NULL)
        {
            node->south = insertNode(node->south, raw_data, raw_coordinates, moveSouth(position));
        }
        else if (insertNode(node->west, raw_data, raw_coordinates, moveWest(position)) != NULL)
        {
            node->west = insertNode(node->west, raw_data, raw_coordinates, moveWest(position));
        }
        else if (insertNode(node->east, raw_data, raw_coordinates, moveEast(position)) != NULL)
        {
            node->east = insertNode(node->east, raw_data, raw_coordinates, moveEast(position));
        }

        return node;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question? You literally just posted a description of your pgoram.

Comment: What did you observe when stepping through your code using the debugger?

Comment: Well I keep receiving a segmentation fault so I was wondering if somebody could help me fix it.

Comment: Please post a [MCVe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with an example of inputs that cause a segmentation fault.

Comment: Run the code in the debugger than came with your development environment. The debugger will halt execution when it segfaults. Use the debugger to inspect the variables involved and the backtrace to see how you got there.

Comment: Coordinates start_c; //constructor sets coordinates to (0,0);
    Data data1; //constructor automatically inserts letter 'a'
    Node *start = newNode(data1, start_c);
    insertNode(start, data1, moveNorth(start_c), start_c);// this should insert start->north.

Comment: @JonathanAguilera Edit your post to include that example (instead of as a comment) in a formatted code tag.

Comment: If only I could have a dollar for every question about a linked list on SO... Regardless, I'm certain your question has been asked before. Have you tried looking at other questions about linked lists on SO? Have you tried using a debugger, as other commentators have suggested? If you're in school, have you talked to any classmates or TA's or the professor for help?

Answer (score 0):

I would hazard a guess that your `if (node == null)` branch isn't working how you intended.

*Assuming* that `compare_coordinates` returns true if the current position is "where you need to be", you'll immediately return a new node. **This doesn't add the new node into the mesh you're building**, so the next time you try to get to that node, it'll be generated again.

Similarly, if `compare_coordinates` returns false, it looks like you're just giving up the search - the approach I believe you had in mind would likely add a new "empty" node at the current location, then recurse on that node with the current parameters to "get to where you need to be".

All speculation, as there's no comments and explanations of vital parts of the code are missing, but this would result in your grid never expanding beyond a single central node, which could cause null-pointer dereferences causing segfaults.